# Jmeter- Jenkins performance plugin report exponents numbers

Tags: jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am able to generate performance trend report using Jenkins Performance plugin. In performance report what is the significance/meaning of the exponent numbers highlighted in red color in below image. Example -2, +5698, -6657 etc. Not able to find any information related to this
[image]

Comment: Either answer is trivial: they are a comparison to previous build (e.g. first row had 3 samples on previous build, and their average was 5698 ms faster). Or I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

The +value indicates that this build contributed to increase in the response time from the previous build by that 'value'.

Ex: In your case, for the first URI, the average response time increased by +5698 ms, similarly incase of -ve value, it means the current build is faster than the previous by that value. I was able to verify this on my performance trend report.

However i am not sure what the + and - equates to in the "samples" column. Let me know if this works!